# Recombine sheets with multiple level of headers, and write out an excel file with different sheets named by one level of header

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

Suppose we have an excel file (you can download sample data from [this link](https://www.dropbox.com/scl/fi/ds6jit37jm8hkoocuusvk/test_data_2022-10-25.xlsx?dl=0&rlkey=6n7t7kdsohta7gc3q1hzbcj9k)), which contains several sheets with three-layer headers. At present, the data is divided into different sheets according to the `Indicator Name`.

```
      Country Name             Mexico            Moldova
0   Indicator Name            PPP_GDP            PPP_GDP
1   Indicator Code  NY.GDP.PCAP.PP.CD  NY.GDP.PCAP.PP.CD
2             1988                NaN                NaN
3             1989               8.9                 NaN
4             1990               9.9              102.5 
5             1991               9.9              103.4 
6             1992               9.8              105.4 
7             1993               9.7              101.6 
8             1994               9.7              101.2 
9             1995               9.6              100.2 
10            1996               9.5               99.8 
11            1997               9.4               99.2 
12            1998               9.2               99.3 
13            1999               9.0               99.4 
14            2000                NaN                NaN
```

Now I hope to re-arrange them into different sheets according to the `Country Name`, how to do it?

My attempt is to loop each sheet, merge them horizontally into a large sheet, and then regroup it according to the `Country Name`.

```
sheets = [PPP_GDP, CPI, PPI]
final = []
for sheet in sheets:
    df = pd.read_excel('./test_data_2022-10-25.xlsx', sheet_name=sheet, header=[0, 1, 2])
    final.append(df)
    
excel_merged = pd.concat(final, ignore_index=True)
excel_merged.to_excel('./output.xlsx')
```

Out:

[image]

So the question is how could we split dataframe to four sheets as follows:

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Note that I gave the expected result in the sample data: a new excel file containing `Mexico`, `Moldova`, `Nepal` and `Israel` as sheets.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create index by first column by `index_col=0` in `read_excel`, join by `pd.concat` with `axis=1` and last create sheetnames by country names form first level of MultiIndex:

```
sheets = ['PPP_GDP', 'CPI', 'PPI']
df = pd.concat([pd.read_excel('./test_data_2022-10-25.xlsx', 
                              sheet_name=sheet, 
                              header=[0, 1, 2], 
                              index_col=0) 
                 for sheet in sheets], axis=1)


writer = pd.ExcelWriter('output.xlsx', engine='xlsxwriter')

for name, g in df.groupby(level=0, axis=1):
    g.to_excel(writer, sheet_name=name)

writer.save()
```